# Как посчитать количество слов в минуту

Tags: javascript

Есть условная строка, формирующаяся через гугловское API voice-to-speech, необходимо посчитать скорость чтения - количество слов в минуту

Comment: Если это строка, то например превратить ее в массив методом `.split(' ')` а потом взять количество элементов `.length`

Comment: а скорость то как посчитать в миунуту

Comment: Если в ответе нет времени работы, то никак... Ну или каким то экзотическим методом, засечь время отправки, время приема, посчитать слова и поделить на время